# Opencv_photo not found Error, on installing opencv gem in rails 4?

Tags: ruby, opencv, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to install opencv gem in rails 4 application using the following command,

```
gem install ruby-opencv -- --with-opencv-dir=/usr/local
```

It is giving  opencv_photo not found error,

ERROR:

```
Building native extensions with: '--with-opencv-dir=/usr/local'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-opencv:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/vijaya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-opencv-dir=/usr/local
>> Check the required libraries...

checking for main() in -lstdc++... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_calib3d... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_contrib... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_core... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_features2d... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_flann... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_highgui... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_imgproc... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_legacy... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_ml... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_objdetect... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_video... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_photo... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/vijaya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
    --with-opencv-dir
    --with-opencv-include
    --without-opencv-include=${opencv-dir}/include
    --with-opencv-lib
    --without-opencv-lib=${opencv-dir}/lib
    --with-libxml2-dir
    --without-libxml2-dir
    --with-libxml2-include
    --without-libxml2-include=${libxml2-dir}/include
    --with-libxml2-lib
    --without-libxml2-lib=${libxml2-dir}/lib
    --with-stdc++lib
    --without-stdc++lib
    --with-opencv_calib3dlib
    --without-opencv_calib3dlib
    --with-opencv_contriblib
    --without-opencv_contriblib
    --with-opencv_corelib
    --without-opencv_corelib
    --with-opencv_features2dlib
    --without-opencv_features2dlib
    --with-opencv_flannlib
    --without-opencv_flannlib
    --with-opencv_highguilib
    --without-opencv_highguilib
    --with-opencv_imgproclib
    --without-opencv_imgproclib
    --with-opencv_legacylib
    --without-opencv_legacylib
    --with-opencv_mllib
    --without-opencv_mllib
    --with-opencv_objdetectlib
    --without-opencv_objdetectlib
    --with-opencv_videolib
    --without-opencv_videolib
    --with-opencv_photolib
    --without-opencv_photolib
extconf.rb:58:in `block in <main>': opencv_photo not found. (RuntimeError)
    from extconf.rb:58:in `each'
    from extconf.rb:58:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/vijaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@live/gems/ruby-opencv-0.0.13 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/vijaya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@live/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/ruby-opencv-0.0.13/gem_make.out
```

How to fix it?

we are using

ubuntu = 12.04

Ruby Version = 2.1.1

Rails Version = 4.1.0

Can any one help me in fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed opencv? 
if not downloaded it from here http://opencv.org/downloads.html.
Install it and then do gem install gem install ruby-opencv